# SQLite auto increment issue

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite

I have created a SQLite database in C# and i used that query to create a table.

```
string q = "create table mains ( id int IDENTITY, desc varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY(id) )"; 
ExecuteQuery(q);
```

And i tried adding a record like that :

```
string txtSQLQuery = "insert into  mains (desc) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "')";
ExecuteQuery(txtSQLQuery);
```

I just added a desc and not ID , i guess it should auto increment the id field but it does not.
Instead it adds the desc and the the ID field is empty every time i add a new record

EDIT :
i tried using :

```
id int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

But got Error :

```
SQLite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT":
```

EDIT 2 :
I get that when i load the records :

[image]

There are no Numbers in the ID field at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
create table mains (id INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY, desc varchar(20))
```

> A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will autoincrement.

[Taken from sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/65cd3/1)

### Edit

As an alternative try executing

```
string txtSQLQuery = "insert into mains (id, desc) values (NULL, '" + textBox1.Text + "')";
```

Comment: Tried that but check the picture i just uploaded on the question please

Comment: Something else is wrong here. See [this working SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/65cd3/1)

Comment: YES IT WORKS , the Null had to be inserted , Thanks a lot

Comment: Keep in mind you have to use `INTEGER` and not `INT`, as the latter will not be automatically incremented or filled at all.

Answer (score 2):

IDENTITY is not part of the SQLite language.  Use AUTOINCREMENT instead:

```
 create table mains ( id int AUTOINCREMENT, desc varchar(20), PRIMARY KEY(id) )
```

or

```
 create table mains ( id int PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, desc varchar(20))
```

Comment: it says : SQLite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error
i guess AUTOINCREMENT isn't valid ?

Comment: Yes, AUTOINCREMENT is valid: http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html.  Did you drop the old table before CREATEing the new one?

Comment: Use INTEGER instead of `int`.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d0742/2.  Also, VARCHAR(20) is meaningless to SQLite, but it will correctly map to TEXT.